# SQL Server : sum particular column for this year and last year

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT
    a.ERSDataValues_ERSCommodity_ID,c.ersGeographyDimension_country,
    b.ERSTimeDimension_Year,
    SUM(a.ERSDataValues_AttributeValue) as Total
FROM
    cosd.ERSDataValues a, cosd.ERSTimeDimension_LU b,
    cosd.ERSGeographyDimension_LU c
WHERE
    a.ERSDataValues_ERSCommodity_ID IN (SELECT ERSBusinessLogic_InputDataSeries
                                        FROM [AnimalProductsCoSD].[CoSD].[ERSBusinessLogic]
                                        WHERE ERSBusinessLogic_InputGeographyDimensionID = 7493
                                          AND ERSBusinessLogic_InputTimeDimensionValue = 'all months'
                                          AND ERSBusinessLogic_Type = 'time aggregate')
  AND a.ERSDataValues_ERSTimeDimension_ID = b.ERSTimeDimension_ID
  AND c.ersGeographyDimension_country != 'WORLD'
  AND a.ERSDataValues_ERSGeography_ID = c.ERSGeographyDimension_ID                  
GROUP BY
    b.ERSTimeDimension_Year, a.ERSDataValues_ERSCommodity_ID,
    c.ersGeographyDimension_country
ORDER BY 
     b.ERSTimeDimension_Year, a.ERSDataValues_ERSCommodity_ID
```

All I want is that sum function above to return sum from Jan 2018 to june 2018 and also I want a sum from previous year for the same time period. I do not want to hardcode the months but I rather want it dynamically.

I thought of using conditional aggregrate functions, but the output does not match to my requirement . Any ideas ?

This is the output I want: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyI1b.jpg

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: It was not an error , but not the output I wanted.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0):

You can add a filter to a where clause to limit time dimension to current and previous year, and then add something like this to both the SELECT list and GROUP BY:

```
CASE 
WHEN YEAR(b.date)=YEAR(GETDATE()) THEN 'Current Year' 
WHEN YEAR(b.date)=YEAR(GETDATE())-1 THEN 'Previous Year'
ELSE NULL
END
```

It may look a little different depending on how you define current and previous year, but that's the idea.

In terms of limiting Jan to June this has to be in the WHERE clause. If you do not want to hard-code specific months (Jan/June) then I think you have to reference something else from you time dimension - e.g. if you have quarter attribute you can say quarter_number in (1,2).

Comment: there is no column called date in the table

Comment: Well the name may be difference - I was referring to the column in your time storing date attribute.

Comment: @BharatRadhakrishnan Please provide DDL+DML, meaning Queries to CREATE your table(s) including indexes, and Queries to INSERT sample data. This will give us the tools to reproduce the issue and test our solution.

Comment: @RonenAriely The data is sensitive to give out but I can give DDLs. how can I attach here.

Comment: Hi @BharatRadhakrishnan, I am not familiar with the interface here. In other discussion's forums you can simply add a response with the missing info, but here you can add only poor comments (clear text) or answers. The options that I see are (1) add code in answer message: bad idea since this is not answer, (2) add code to original message: awful idea since it make all the comment irrelevant and the next person that will come to this thread will not understand what we spoke about since the question was changed (3) add information in external site and give us the link; I dont think this allowed

Comment: and since I am limited by short comment I have to split it... and here is the addition: you do not need to add real data but sample/demo data only for the discussion. You should also add only relevant column in the table since we do not want unnecessary information. In addition post the result that you want to get related to the sample data